# Javascript example using FluorineFx Aperture in Adobe Air

Tags: javascript, air, adobe, fluorinefx

This is my first time posting. If anything worng, please forgive me.

My question is that has anyone used "**FluorineFx Aperture**" framework in Adobe Air using Javascript language? I would like to see some samples of the codes to get an idea.
Please help out.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do, if I can help you. You can also go through this page if it can help you more.

http://aperture.fluorinefx.com/?page_id=4